# How to use an Author Name based Citation style with unusual Sources

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

Trying to solve this Problem i got so many Problems. 
First of all, how should you deal with sources that just don't have a Year or an author, like non-Static websites... of course, you have `urldate` but at least `natbib` (witch I am currently using) doesn't seem to know how to deal with it... 
Over all `natbib` just doesn't want to work. 
`Bib.bib`:

```
@Article{Alonso2004,
  author     = {Angel Alonso and Marcos Reyes and Zoran Sodnik},
  title      = {Performance of satellite-to-ground communications link between {ARTEMIS} and the Optical Ground Station},
  year       = {2004},
  month      = {nov},
  abstract   = {...},
  booktitle  = {{SPIE} Proceedings},
  doi        = {10.1117/12.565516},
  editor     = {John D. Gonglewski and Karin Stein},
  priority   = {prio1},
  publisher  = {{SPIE}},
  ranking    = {rank5},
  readstatus = {skimmed},
}
@Misc{modulationPicture,
  author       = {Michel Bakni},
  howpublished = {CC BY-SA 4.0 <https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0>, via Wikimedia Commons},
  title        = {Modulation Übersichts Bild},
  groups       = {Bilder},
  url          = {https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e7/Modulation_categorization.svg},
}
@Misc{DIN44302,
  title = {DIN 44302},
}
@Website{starlink,
  groups    = {Websites},
  timestamp = {2023-07-08},
  title     = {Starlink},
  url       = {https://www.starlink.com},
  urldate   = {2023-07-03},
}
```

My `.tex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[square , sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Exam}

Some Text\cite[p. 250]{Alonso2004}

\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

As you see I have many Entries that don't have a clear Year.
I get following Error `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` that hinders Compiling.
One solution I could think of was switching between a Number and Author Year based Citation Style. Is ther a way to do that in LaTeX?
Thanks to all of you trying to help me!!! 
Edit:*emphasized text*

1. sqare to square

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: You should change `title = {DIN 44302},` to `title = {{DIN} 44302},` in order to keep BibTeX from changing the acronym "DIN" to "Din".

Answer (score 0):

> One solution I could think of was switching between a Number and Author Year based Citation Style. Is ther[e] a way to do that in LaTeX?

Short answer: Yes.

Slightly longer answer: Change

```
\usepackage[square, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

to

```
\usepackage[numbers, square, sort&compress]{natbib}
```

and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: But this gives me just Number References (`[1]`) and not Author, Year References, I am searching for a way to switch between them dynamically in one document.

Comment: @Sedoc - How are your readers supposed to make sense of a system of citation call-outs in which some show surnames  and years and others show just numbers? If you *must* employ an authoyear-style citation call-out system, you better start changing fields such as `title = {DIN 44302},` to `author = {{DIN 44302}},`, etc.